# No such method Error when accessing JAX RS CXF web service

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, cxf

I am getting no such method error when I try to access my JAX RS CXF web service.
These are the jars that I have added in the build path:

```
cxf-core-3.1.2.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.2.jar
cxf-rt-rs-client-3.1.2.jar
cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers-3.1.2.jar
cxf-rt-rs-extension-search-3.1.2.jar
cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.2.jar
httpclient-4.4.1.jar
httpcore-4.4.1.jar
httpcore-nio-4.4.1.jar
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar
jettison-1.3.7.jar
spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
stax2-api-3.1.4.jar
xml-resolver-1.2.jar
xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar    
xmlsec-2.0.5.jar
```

J2EE version is 2.3, Application server is weblogic 12

I know it is some jar issue. But I am not able to resolve it. This is the error thrown:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException.validate(Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;
    at javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException.(NotFoundException.java:126)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.SpecExceptions.toNotFoundException(SpecExceptions.java:89)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.ExceptionUtils.toNotFoundException(ExceptionUtils.java:122)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:169)
```

Comment: This is the generic error cxf throws when it encounters any problem. Try changing the log level to DEBUG to get appropriate stack trace. You can also try enabling cxf logging by setting a system property org.apache.cxf.logging.enabled to true .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class and method might be present and conflicting with any of the weblogic jars

In your weblogic.xml present in WEB-INF, add javax.ws.rs.* package to instruct weblogic to prefer the package from your WAR classpath as shown below,

`<package-name>javax.ws.rs.*</package-name>`

Sample weblogic.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsdhttp://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-apphttp://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <container-descriptor>  
        <prefer-application-packages>  
            <package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.eclipse.persistence.*</package-name>
            <package-name>javax.ws.rs.*</package-name>
        </prefer-application-packages>  
    </container-descriptor>  
</weblogic-web-app>
```