# nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException.validate

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In my application, while I validate the request object I throw BadRequestException() depending on the scenario. But the actual exception that is thrown is as follows.

```
2018-01-24 15:19:21.963 ERROR 4220 --- [nio-5002-exec-6] c.w.s.s.handler.GenericExceptionHandler  : Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException.validate(Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status$Family;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException.validate(Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status$Family;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:982)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.myproject.util.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:26)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException.validate(Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status$Family;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;
    at javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException.<init>(ClientErrorException.java:80)
    at javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException.<init>(BadRequestException.java:71)
    at com.myproject.service.impl.MyServiceImpl.setDetails(MyServiceImpl.java:177)
    at com.myproject.service.impl.MyServiceImpl.retrieveDetails(MyServiceImpl.java:107)
    at com.myproject.controller.MyController.myServicePost(MyController.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    ... 65 common frames omitted
```

I tried the following to fix it.

1. updated the javax.ws.rs-api.jar to the latest version from 2.0 to 2.1
2. [spring-web was not included in the pom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44091620/spring-boot-handler-dispatch-failed-nested-exception-is-java-lang-nosuchmetho)
3. [trail 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347069/no-such-method-error-when-accessing-jax-rs-cxf-web-service?rq=1)
   And a few others example. But no luck.

I opened the Class ClientErrorException from the JAR. When I tried to click on validate method in its constructor's super call I could not find any implementation for that method.

```
public ClientErrorException(Response.Status status) {
        super((Throwable) null, validate(Response.status(status).build(), Response.Status.Family.CLIENT_ERROR));
    }
```

I require BadRequestException() to be thrown, not the NoSuchMethodError mentioned above. Please help me with the issue.

Comment: If you are using eclipse can you go to the dependency hierarchy of your highest level pom file and search for javax.ws.rs-api.jar, make sure you do not have multiple jars of a different version.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rakesh. I just checked. Although there are multiple entries, all the entries are omitted except one. 
Also, I have one basic question. In the class ClientErrorException, why is validate method missing? Please refer to the code snippet mentioned in the question.

Comment: it is inherited from super class

Comment: if it is inherited from the super class, then when I click on the validate method it should have to taken me to that implementation, but it did not. adding to that I check all its super classes. There is no "validate" method.

Comment: That is why you are getting that issue. Check the version of the jar from which WebApplicationException.class is coming from

Comment: I'm having the same issue. How would I "Check the version of the jar from which WebApplicationException.class is coming from" ?

Comment: @Camilla If you are using eclipse or STS press cmd+shift+T[I am using Mac] and type in the name of the file. You will see the jars from where the file is being referenced

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @Rakesh, I was able to fix the issue. The issue was from the class `WebApplicationException` which is the parent of the class `ClientErrorException`.

`WebApplicationException`class was referenced from the jar `jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar`. This version of the JAR did not have the latest version of the class `WebApplicationException` that had the `validate` method. 
So, I excluded this JAR to fix the issue.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: In my case, I use the exclusion tag like the example and removed this dependency: `<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
  </dependency>`

Answer (score 1):

In my case i am using header **Content-Type=multipart/form-data** and not attaching the file while making request. I attach the file and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently seen this exception when testing locally and *forgetting to set the `Content-Type` HTTP header correctly*.

In my specific case, I had accidentally set it to `application/json` instead of *`application/xml`* (the correct value).

Hope that helps.